# Best expression using Regex for extracting Email-Preference from large text files

Tags: python, regex, bash, awk, sed

Currently I am trying to parse a large text file with mixed content. However am interested in filtering only lines which satisfy this requirement.

Email-Preference

I am able to find the regex for email however the preceding ":" followed by preference in text is currently my challenge. Single character matching with "?" doesnt help much though.

Any suggestions on this would be much appreciated.

Sample from text source:

```
Warning: You are using an old IOS image for this router.
Sending 5, 100-byte ICMP Echos to abacus, timeout is 2 seconds:
Sending 5, 100-byte ICMP Echos to abacus, timeout is 2 seconds:
timeout xlate 3:00:00
timeout conn 1:00:00 half-closed 0:10:00 udp 0:02:00 icmp 0:00:02
timeout sunrpc 0:10:00 h323 0:05:00 h225 1:00:00 mgcp 0:05:00 mgcp-pat 0:05:00
timeout sip 0:30:00 sip_media 0:02:00 sip-invite 0:03:00 sip-disconnect 0:02:00
timeout sip-provisional-media 0:02:00 uauth 0:05:00 absolute
timeout tcp-proxy-reassembly 0:01:00
myemail@gmail.com-prefmenuonly
timeout floating-conn 0:00:00
  destination address http https://tools.cisco.com/its/service/oddce/services/DDCEService
Cryptochecksum:checksum
: end
Sending 5, 100-byte ICMP Echos to abacus, timeout is 2 seconds:
Sending 5, 100-byte ICMP Echos to abacus, timeout is 2 seconds:
secondmail@gmail.com-selectedprefonly
```

Output should be :

myemail@gmail.com-prefmenuonly

secondmail@mail.com-selectedprefonly

Comment: RavinderSingh13 : I have not added any code in this question. Just plain text with sample data for reference.

Comment: Thank you for your swift responses. If you look at the sample shown for output, it will contain the preferences. All emails will have a separator "-" and then the preference text after that. Idea here is to get them together as well.

Comment: Thanks . It was close. Based on your suggestion, I was able to improvise and it worked. Working solution : awk 'match($0,/[^@]+@[^@]+\.[^@]+/)'  input_file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python is very powerful language and have a good support of regex.

Above task could be accomplished through below code-

```
import re

txt = """
one can contact us at xays.adf@gmail.com, asd@cd.in, askdj123_23@sjsgdf-sdfsd.co.uk.in and so and so
"""

print(re.findall(r"[a-zA-z0-9_\-\.]+@[a-zA-z0-9_\-\.]+",txt))
```

Output would be -

```
['xays.adf@gmail.com', 'asd@cd.in', 'askdj123_23@sjsgdf-sdfsd.co.uk.in']
```

similarly it will catch below output for your input string-

```
['myemail@gmail.com-prefmenuonly', 'secondmail@gmail.com-selectedprefonly']
```

Answer (score 0):

***EDIT:*** Since OP is asking to print the complete line of match then following should be used.

```
awk 'match($0,/[a-zA-Z]+@[a-zA-Z]+\.com/)' Input_file
```

---

Following `awk` may help you here.

```
awk 'match($0,/[a-zA-Z]+@[a-zA-Z]+\.com/){print substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)}'  Input_file
```

Comment: @My Email, could you please let me know reason of removing correct answer from here?